# Return multiple rows and multiple columns using spark sql in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a customer transactions table with 4 columns(customerID,productName,trxDate,trxAmt) where I should be able to pass my customerID and get all the transaction details(i.e. productName,trxDate,trxAmt) for that customerID.
I tried below statement:

```
custID=1001
spark.sql("select * from mydatabase.cust_trans where customerID={}").format(custID).show()
```

But somehow I am getting below error when I execute it:

```
ParseException: "\nmismatched input 'from' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 9)\n\n== SQL ==\nselect * from mydatabse.cust_trans where customerID={}\n---------^^^\n"
```

Comment: the `.format()` is placed incorrectly. it should be chaining the string inside the `sql()`. e.g. `spark.sql('select * from {0}'.format(tbl)).show()`